# Using jQuery to find if any drop down (out of multiple) has a selected value with index > 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a page with a changing number of dropdowns (changes by user). For each of them, the default option (index 0) is a standard 'Please Select ###'.

I need to see if ANY of them were selected, at least one.

I found something using jQuery.index, but i'm not sure if this is expected behavior, or a fluke.

```
<select id=dd1 class=dropdown>
   <option> Select</option>
             ...
   <option> Select</option>
</select>


<select id=dd2 class=dropdown>
   <option> Select</option>
             ...
   <option> Select</option>
</select>
```

(and possibly more)

```
$(".dropdown > option:selected").index()
```

The behavior i'm seeing is that the return value is the **Added up** indexes.

Can I trust this functionality, or is there another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can test `$('selector:selected').index() === -1`. The more common way is to test `$('selector:selected').length === 0` though.

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken, there is always a selected option. The length will simply return how many Select elements I have

Comment: If you want to remove the default option from the set the selector returns you could add a class to it and use `$(...).not('.ignoreMe').length` (or as the answer below suggests do the opposite operation `.filter('.doNotIgnoreMe')`) :)

Comment: And yes, `.length` returns the length of the array of matched elements. I assume that's what _at least one_ meant?

Comment: my point was that $('selector:selected').length would count the amount of Select elements regardless of what option is chosen. Not what i wanted.

Comment: No, actually, it returns a handle to the currently selected `option` tag. A simple demostration: http://jsfiddle.net/BF22p/

Comment: you're ignoring the fact that the question is about dealing with more than one Select. Also, my response was for your first comment.  The example with giving a class to the first option and using that obviously works. In any case, my issue is resolved, so thanks anyway for your response.

Comment: No, I'm not. It works in exactly the same way for multiple selects, eg: http://jsfiddle.net/BF22p/1/ As for the classes, the only advantage they have is that they're cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out ones that have been selected and have an index > 0 - then check the length to see how many have actually changed

```
$(".dropdown option:selected").filter(function(){
       return $(this).index() > 0; // check index against siblings
}).length; // <-- this will return how many are not index 0
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fc66z/)

Or this would work also

```
$(".dropdown").filter(function(){
   return this.selectedIndex > 0; // check selectedIndex property of select element
}).length;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qLs7X/)

<kbd>[EXAMPLE FOR TESTING > 0](http://jsfiddle.net/A93X9/)</kbd>
<kbd>[EXAMPLE FOR TESTING == 0](http://jsfiddle.net/F2427/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Define a value property for each option in the select dropdown like this.

```
<select id=dd1 class=dropdown>
   <option value="0"> Select</option>
         ...
   <option value="n"> Select</option>
</select>
```

Inside javascript, do this:

```
if(parseInt($("#dd1").val()) > 0 ){
  //do something here:
}
```

For all dropdowns in the form:

```
$("select").each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 0){
        //Do something here:
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple dropdowns in selection you should use `$.each()` function, and then threat individually, or if you will select only a single dropdown you can use **user1515084** solution.

```
$(".dropdown").each(function() {    
console.log($(this).attr("selectedIndex")); 
}
```

Comment: This makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the first option:

```
<select id=dd1 class=dropdown>
   <option class="empty"> Select</option>
             ...
   <option> Select</option>
</select>


<select id=dd2 class=dropdown>
   <option class="empty"> Select</option>
             ...
   <option> Select</option>
</select>
```

Then check the number of empty selections against the number of selects

```
var bValid = $(".dropdown option.empty:selected").length < $(".dropdown").length;
```

Update: Improved to count non-empties.

```
var bValid = $(".dropdown option:not(.empty):selected").length > 0;
```

Comment: That's creative. I like this answer.